# Symmetry group of a Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, group-theory

I apologise in advance for my English.
I would like to ask you about this exercise that was assigned by the professor during class.

> Consider the Lagrangian density:
>
> $$\mathcal{L}=-\partial_{\mu}\Phi^{\dagger}\partial^{\mu}\Phi\space+\space\Phi^{\dagger}\eta\Phi\space-\space\frac{1}{2}(\Phi^{\dagger}\Phi)^2$$
>
> where $\Phi$ is a complex scalar field with 4 components:
> $\Phi(x) = \begin{bmatrix}\Phi_1(x)\\\Phi_2(x)\\\Phi_3(x)\\\Phi_4(x)\end{bmatrix}$ and $\eta = diag\lbrace-1,1,1,1\rbrace$.
>
> a) What is the group of linear transformations $\Phi(x)\rightarrow S\Phi(x)$, with $S\in Mat(4,\mathbb{C})$, preserving the kinetic term and the potential, respectively?
>
> b) For which constant values $\Phi_0 = \begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\\c_4\end{bmatrix}$ the Euler-Lagrange equations are satisfied and what is the residual symmetry group? (Otherwise, which matrices $S$ satisfy $\Phi_0\rightarrow S\Phi_0 = \Phi_0$)

I was thinking about doing something like this for **point A**:

1. for the kinetic term:

$$-\partial_{\mu} (S\Phi)^{\dagger} \partial^{\mu} (S\Phi) = -\partial_{\mu} (\Phi^{\dagger}) \partial^{\mu}(\Phi)$$

then since $\partial_{\mu}$ doesn't act on $S$ I would get:

$$-S^{\dagger}S\partial_{\mu}(\Phi^{\dagger})\partial^{\mu}(\Phi) = -\partial_{\mu} (\Phi^{\dagger}) \partial^{\mu}(\Phi)$$

and so: $S^{\dagger}S = \mathbb{1}_4$. So, I would say that if $S$ is a unitary matrix, the kinetic term is preserved.

2. for the other terms the transformation would yield:
   $$\Phi^{\dagger}S^{\dagger}\eta S\Phi\space-\space\frac{1}{2}(\Phi^{\dagger}S^{\dagger}S\Phi)^2 \space = \space \Phi^{\dagger}\eta\Phi\space-\space\frac{1}{2}(\Phi^{\dagger}\Phi)^2$$

So I would get again that: $S^{\dagger}S = \mathbb{1}_4$ in order to preserve the last term, and also $S^{\dagger}\eta S = \eta$ to preserve the first term.

Assuming that what I did makes sense, I have that $S$ must be unitary but also $S$ must satisfy $S^{\dagger}\eta S = \eta$ which (if I'm not mistaken) is the defining condition for a Lorentz transformation.

I don't understand if I can "unify" the two conditions in a single one, since the question asks for "a group".

Regarding **point B**, I would write the Euler-Lagrange equations for a field:

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \Phi} - \partial_{\mu}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_{\mu} \Phi}\right)=0$$

Then I would calculate the derivatives but I'm not sure about how to put the $\Phi_0$ in the game.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Hi, OK I'm sorry I didn't know.